# registerEvent in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have 2 small plugins:

1. In `Authentication` group and works on `onUserAuthenticate` event
2. In `System` group and works on `onAfterRoute` event

As 2 plugins i need to install 2 zip-files. Is it possible with `registerEvent` function create 1 plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Mhm... on my opinion you should keep two different plugins.

Infact you *could* call a plugin from another, but what if the user just installed one and not the other?
Moreover, you can trigger an `event`, not a single plugin.
This means that you'll trigger **all** the plugin linked to that event, not just your.

IMHO you should use two plugins or you can get some errors that will be a nightmare to debug.